# In Intellij, strange english charagter, what happend?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Strange English]

Sometimes my font goes strange like above. And I can't revert until I restart Intellij.

How can I change the font to normal?

I tried to find a setting for this, but I couldn't. And I can't even think of a keyword related to this.

Comment: Am I got it right that all you need to make it normal is restart IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov Yes. If i restart the IDE the font turn into normal. But i don't want to restart my IDE each time this happen.

Comment: @markjukedebug Looks like a bug you should log an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Have you tried to run with default settings ("File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default settings")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found when this happen. Key combination of 'Alt' + 'Window' + '='